# Silverlight Conditional CheckBox/RadioButton

Tags: silverlight, templates, silverlight-3.0, radio-button

Imagine I had a list of names, each paired with a value ("C" for CheckBox or "R" for RadioButton).

Can I put together a template to display the correct control based on the given value?

For instance if I have "Name0, C" I'd like to display a CheckBox labeled Name0.
If I have "Name1, R" I'd like to display a RadioButton labeled Name1.

Any ideas? Or is this even possible using only a template? Perhaps I would need to make the determination in the code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a data template that has both a Checkbox and RadioButton.  You could then create a type converter for `ValueToVisability` to display one and hide the other.